# How to clip unclosed path in Qt QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have `QGraphicsView` with `QGraphicsScene` and I need to draw unclosed paths (which may contain lines, or Bezier curves) in limited area of `scene` defined by `rect`.

There is simple way to clip **closed** path by using `QPainterPath.intersected(path)` function, but if `path` is **unclosed**, then `intersected` closes it (adds line from end to start point).

Here is the simplified code that illustrates my problem:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import functools
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

def path_through_points(points):
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.moveTo(*points[0])
    for x, y in points[1:]:
        path.lineTo(x, y)
    return path

def path_through_points_workaround(points):
    return path_through_points(points + list(reversed(points)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)
    rect = QRectF(0, 0, 300, 300)

    clip = QPainterPath()
    clip.addRect(rect)

    points = [(50, 50), (100, 100), (500, 300)]

    def test_draw(path):
        scene.clear()
        scene.addRect(rect)
        scene.addPath(path)

    unclosed_path = path_through_points(points)
    closed_path = path_through_points_workaround(points)

    QTimer.singleShot(0, functools.partial(test_draw, unclosed_path))
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, functools.partial(test_draw, unclosed_path.intersected(clip)))
    QTimer.singleShot(4000, functools.partial(test_draw, closed_path.intersected(clip)))

    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It draws generated path:

1. Without clipping.
2. With clipping (path closes instead of just clip) - this is unacceptable for me.
3. And finally, results that I want to get (but it's reached with workaround).

Workaround: close `path` by drawing it in `reversed` order. But my `path` may contain many lines/beziers, so it's ineffective, and anti aliasing looks bad with doubled lines.

So question is how to clip unclosed path or line in QGraphicsScene without changing logic of path generation function?

**UPDATE**

Now I'm using following function:

```python
def clipped_path(path, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y):
    """ Returns clipped path, supports unclosed paths of any kind
    (lines, beziers)

    NOTE: Resulting path can loose antialiasing
    """
    path.connectPath(path.toReversed())
    clip = QPainterPath()
    clip.addRect(QRectF(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y))
    return path.intersected(clip)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Better method as [@Hello W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326964/hello-w) suggested:

```python
class ClippedItemMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y):
        self._clip_path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self._clip_path.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y))
        super(ClippedItemMixin, self).__init__()

    def paint(self, painter, *args, **kwargs):
        painter.setClipPath(self._clip_path)
        super(ClippedItemMixin, self).paint(painter, *args, **kwargs)


class ClippedPathItem(ClippedItemMixin, QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem):
   pass
```

Now it looks nicer, because anti aliasing works right.

Comment: +1 Thanks, the `path.connectPath(path.toReversed())` trick is great!

Comment: [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67330) filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subclassing from `QGraphicsPathItem` and then reimplementing the paint method of it and calling `painter.setClipRect()`